# CloudFormation cnf-lint Obsolete "DependsOn"

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

When running cfn-lint on the following code I get a warning

```
"MicroserviceSG": {
   "Type": "AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup",
⚠  "DependsOn": "MicroserviceLoadBalancerSGPrivate",
   "Properties": {
      "GroupName": {"Fn::Join": ["-", [{"Ref": "Name"}, {"Ref": "Env"}, "container-sg"]]},
      "GroupDescription": "HTTP",
         "VpcId": {"Ref": "VpcId"},
         "SecurityGroupIngress": [
            {
                "IpProtocol": "tcp",
                "FromPort": 80,
                "ToPort": 80,
                "SourceSecurityGroupId": { "Ref": "MicroserviceLoadBalancerSGPrivate" }
             }
           ]
        }
    },
```

```
W3005 Obsolete DependsOn on resource (MicroserviceLoadBalancerSGPrivate),
dependency already enforced by a "Ref" at 
Resources/MicroserviceSG/Properties/SecurityGroupIngress/0/SourceSecurityGroupId/Ref
```

Is this warning valid? Do certain object references perform implicit dependency checks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the warning is valid since the `Ref` usage implicitly defines a dependency on `MicroserviceLoadBalancerSGPrivate`. Technically speaking, *redundant* would be more correct than *obsolete*.

Unless you specifically need `MicroserviceSG` to be created after `MicroserviceLoadBalancerSGPrivate`, then you should remove the `DependsOn` and let CloudFormation do it's thing, as CloudFormation will optimize and parallelize the deployment.

---

The most common use of the `DependsOn` is to enforce the creation and deletion of resources in a certain order, as mentioned by the documentation:

> You can use the DependsOn attribute with any resource. Here are some typical uses:
> Declare dependencies for resources that must be created or deleted in a specific order

The [DependsOn documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-attribute-dependson.html) has more scenarios on when and why you might want to use `DependsOn`.

Comment: "Unless you specifically need MicroserviceSG to be created after MicroserviceLoadBalancerSGPrivate". This is the original question, are the statements redundant (equal)?  The "DependsOn": "MicroserviceLoadBalancerSGPrivate" statement was added because the CloudFormation template failed without this. I later added the ingress Ref, resulting in the current cnf-lint waring.  I want to remove the DependsOn statement, but my experience is that Ref alone does not guarantee a build order.

Comment: The difference is subtle. DependsOn guarantees that the creation process for resource B will only start after resource A has finish creating. Ref doesn't guarantee this since the creation can be in parallel. `because the CloudFormation template failed without this` .. what was the error?